# n-dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

In python, a 0 filled 2D array can be achieved using:

```
[[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
//where w is the width and h is the height
```

I was wondering, how could this be done so you could create a function which could return a N dimensional array filled with 0s, where the x,y,z,w etc were specified in an array as a parameter.

Example:

```
makeNArray(3, [4, 5, 6])
//would make a 3D array which was 4x5x6
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried several things involving foor loops and while loops but to no avail

Comment: You should include some of that in your post along with the results.

Comment: Give [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) a look. `arr = numpy.zeros((4, 5, 6))`.

Comment: You should consider using Numpy arrays instead of lists.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/120286/78136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some editing I found that I could do:

```
def nDimensionalArray(n, s):
    x = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = [x for j in range(s[i])]
    return x
```

Comment: Have you tried changing anything in the array returned from this? You'll see that it doesn't quite behave as expected...